Double pulse circuit for MOT spot welder
I have a MOT spot welder and I'd like to add a double pulse option with adjustable pulse durations, and delay. I have two 555 chips on hand that I'd like to use. I know there are other chips and better methods to achieve this, but I'm not after the most elegant solution. Just want to put something together with what i got on hand. I already bought a control board to do just this and I don't like anything about it. Too many bells and whistles and the welds just don't come out that strong. It seems to break each pulse into multiple pulses with a time constant of some sort. No bueno

you are asking how to connect two 555 timers to an unknown device
